# project creation error in super sonic framework

Tags: node.js, git, api, supersonic

I am new to work on super sonic framework. I have to create API for the android app on it. So I install the Git and nodejs in my system. Now I am trying to create project so I have used the command on Git command prompt

```
C:\Program Files\Git>steroids create Project1
```

but I am getting error when I run that command. I have attached error's Image. How can I remove that error and create the project. I am new on it so I want to know that can I create API for app without creating own app and installing the framework. If yes, then How? Actually I need to create API for the android app.
[image]

Comment: Is there any way to create API for android on sonic framework, without installing it or creating own app? I have to work on web.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Run` should be capitalized. Try using `run`.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Git>steroids create project1 is also give same error